# How can I change download location in my Mattermost?

Tags: directory, mattermost

I downloaded some files in mattermost chat. And, these files are in C drive download folder, but i want to set default download directory to D drive. How can I do this?

I've found many pages about Mattermost download location, but I couldn't find any information about my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by clicking three dots in the upper left corner > File > Settings > and there is a field "Download Location"